# How to add a function to monitor link clicking using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a short program to automate the process of clicking and saving profiles on LinkedIn.

Brief:

- The program reads from a txt file with a large amount of LI URLs.
- Using Selenium, it opens them one by one, then, hit the "Open in Sales Navigator" button
- A new tab is opening, and on it, it needs to click the "Save" button, and choose the relevant list to save on.

I have two main problems:

1. LinkedIn has 3 versions of the same page. How can I use a condition to check which page version is it? (meaning - if you can't find this button, move to the next version). From what I've seen, you can't really use the "If" function with selenium, cause it causing trouble. Any other suggestions?
2. More important, and the reason I opened this thread - I want to monitor the "failed" links. Let's say I have a list of 1000 LI URLs, and I ran the program to save them on my account. I want to monitor the ones it didn't save or failed to open (broken links, page unavailable, etc.). In order to execute that, I used a CSV file and ordered the program to save all the pages that already saved on this account, but it doesn't solve my problem. How can I make him save all of them and not just the ones that were already saved? (I find it hard to execute because when a page appears as "Unavailable", it jumps to the next one and I couldn't find a way to make him save it.
   It makes it harder to work with it, cause when I put 500 or 1000 URLs, I can't tell which ones save and which ones aren't saved.

Here's the code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv
import random



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=EN')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='assets\chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true")

minDelay=input("\n Please provide min delay in seconds : ")
maxDelay=input("\n Please provide max delay in seconds : ")
listNumber=input("\n Please provide list number : ")
outputFile=input('\n save skipped as?: ')

count=0
closed=2
with open("links.txt", "r") as links:
    for link in links:
        try:
            driver.get(link.strip())
            sleep(3)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='save-to-list-dropdown__trigger ph5 artdeco-button artdeco-button--primary artdeco-button--3 artdeco-button--pro artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view']").click()
            sleep(2)
            count+=1
            if count==1:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='save-to-list-dropdown__content']//ul//li["+str(listNumber)+"]").click()
            else:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='save-to-list-dropdown__content']//ul//li[1]").click()
            sleep(2)
            sleep(random.randint(int(minDelay), int(maxDelay)))
        except:
            if closed==0:
                driver.close()
                sleep(1)
                fileOutput=open(outputFile+".csv", mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
                file_writer = csv.writer(fileOutput, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                file_writer.writerow([link.strip()])
                fileOutput.close()
print("Finished.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The common approach to have different sort of listeners is to use `EventFiringWebDriver`. See the example here:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.abstract_event_listener import AbstractEventListener
from selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver import EventFiringWebDriver


class EventListener(AbstractEventListener):

    def before_click(self, element, driver):
        if element.tag_name == 'a':
            print('Clicking link:', element.get_attribute('href'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver=webdriver.Firefox(), event_listener=EventListener())
    driver.get("https://webelement.click/en/welcome")
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="All Posts"]')
    link.click()
    driver.quit()
```

**UPD:**

Basically your case does not really need that listener. However you can user it. Say you have link file like:

```
https://google.com
https://invalid.url
https://duckduckgo.com/
https://sadfsdf.sdf
https://stackoverflow.com
```

Then the way with `EventFiringWebDriver` would be:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.abstract_event_listener import AbstractEventListener
from selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver import EventFiringWebDriver

broken_urls = []


class EventListener(AbstractEventListener):

    def on_exception(self, exception, drv):
        broken_urls.append(drv.current_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver=webdriver.Firefox(), event_listener=EventListener())
    with open("links.txt", "r") as links:
        for link in links:
            try:
                driver.get(link.strip())
            except:
                print('Cannot reach the link', link.strip())

    print("Finished.")
    driver.quit()

    import csv
    with open('broken_urls.csv', 'w', newline='') as broken_urls_csv:
        wr = csv.writer(broken_urls_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(broken_urls)
```

and without `EventFiringWebDriver` would be:

```py
broken_urls = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    with open("links.txt", "r") as links:
        for link in links:
            stripped_link = link.strip()
            try:
                driver.get(stripped_link)
            except:
                print('Cannot reach the link', link.strip())
                broken_urls.append(stripped_link)

    print("Finished.")
    driver.quit()

    import csv
    with open('broken_urls.csv', 'w', newline='') as broken_urls_csv:
        wr = csv.writer(broken_urls_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(broken_urls)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Alexey R.

TBH, I didn't get the logic. Can you show how can I implement this on my code?
I mean, where should I locate this function and how can I export all of the 'false' results (all of the urls) to a csv file.

Thanks in advance for your help!